# Spring Batch and Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-azure

I am planning to use Spring Batch on Azure as a serverless and looking to explore the Cosmos DB to store and manipulate the data.

Can I still use the Spring Batch Metadata tables with the COSMOS DB? If not, where to store the Spring Batch Metadata tables details?

How can we scheduled Batch Job on Azure? Is there any complete working example?

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB is not a supported database in Spring Batch, but you may be able to use one of the supported types, if the SQL variant is close enough.

Please refer to the [Non-standard Database Types in a Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#nonStandardDatabaseTypesInRepository) section of the documentation for more details and a sample.

Comment: Is there any plan to have a dedicated ItemReader and Writer for Cosmos DB?